# How to avoid forech loop and how we can use array column

Tags: php, php-7

I have one array, in this array i have columns `price`, now i want to do take onle price is equal to 5 as well more than 5. i know using foreach loop we can achieve this, any other way is there to achieve my expected answer ?

```
$mainArray = [
    "key1" => ["name" => "A", "price" => 5],
    "key2" => ["name" => "B", "price" => 7],
    "key3" => ["name" => "C", "price" => 2],
    "key4" => ["name" => "D", "price" => 9]
];
```

> MY CODE

```
  <?php
$mainArray = [
    "key1" => ["name" => "A", "price" => 5],
    "key2" => ["name" => "B", "price" => 7],
    "key3" => ["name" => "C", "price" => 2],
    "key4" => ["name" => "D", "price" => 9]
];

$maxPrice = 5;
$mainArray = array_filter($mainArray, function($value) {
    return $value['price'] >= $maxPrice;
});


print_r($mainArray);

?>
```

but i am getting error `E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: maxPrice -- at line 11`

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop might be a better question. There are some built-in functions you can use, but under the hood they're all looping.

Comment: @ Daan, can you please post your answer ?

Comment: If you want only values in column price you can use my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `array_filter` to check if the price is equal or greater than 5.

```
<?php
$mainArray = [
    "key1" => ["name" => "A", "price" => 5],
    "key2" => ["name" => "B", "price" => 7],
    "key3" => ["name" => "C", "price" => 2],
    "key4" => ["name" => "D", "price" => 9]
];

$maxPrice = 5;
$mainArray = array_filter($mainArray, function($value) use ($maxPrice) {
    return $value['price'] >= 5;
});


var_dump($mainArray);
```

Comment: Here we are checking static value `5`, but my case i am string one variable before the `$mainArray`, i am tried your code i am getting `undefined variables`

Comment: *I am string one variable before the `$mainArray`* What?

Comment: Can you please check my edited code and update your please

Comment: Your variable `$maxPrice` is out of scope. You'll need to add the `use` statement. See my edited answer.

Comment: Why you  don't use my answer? Few days ago i edit my answer when you say "Not working" i just change price to 'price'(add ' ').

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<?php
$mainArray = [
  "key1" => ["name" => "A", "price" => 5],
  "key2" => ["name" => "B", "price" => 7],
  "key3" => ["name" => "C", "price" => 2],
  "key4" => ["name" => "D", "price" => 9]
];
$min = 5;
$result = array_filter(
  $array_column(mainArray, 'price'),
   function ($value) use($min) {
      return ($value >= $min);
   }
);
```